# How to set event order

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have a problem where the events don't flow in the correct order. [image: problem]

When an event spans for multiple months the event changes order on the grey bar. If I set the time frame for the same month - it renders fine. If it is multiple months it goes wrong.

Live Site:
http://vf4.taichungdesigner.com/en/calendar

Comment: Could it be the librarys issue?

Comment: I downloaded the original FullCalendar js and changed the dates and the same problem occurred.